# How to get each status of process from backgroundWorker on front of Form

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a simple Windows based application. I used `BackgroundWorker` for sending mails one by one.
Here is the `DoWork` event handler code

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    MailsSample Mails = e.Argument as MailsSample;
    string readings = "To : " + Mails.To_EmailsID + "- ";

    char[] delimiterChars = { ',' };
    string[] Emails = Mails.To_EmailsID.Split(delimiterChars);

    for (int i = 0; i < Emails.Length; i++)
    {
        try
        {

            SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient(Mails.SMTP, Mails.PORT);
            MailMessage msg = new MailMessage(Mails.From_Email, Emails[i], Mails.subject, Mails.body);
            string mto = null;
            smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(Mails.From_Email, Mails.password);
            smtp.EnableSsl = true;

            msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
            msg.Subject = Mails.subject;

            //if (textBox1.Text != "")
            //{
            //    Attachment at = new Attachment(textBox1.Text);
            //    msg.Attachments.Add(at);
            //}


            msg.Body = Mails.body;
            mto = Emails[i];
            msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
            smtp.Send(msg);


            readings += "Sent Successfully.";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            readings += "Error : " + ex.Message;
        }
        //Mails.t.AppendText ( Environment.NewLine +readings);
    }
    e.Result = readings;
}
```

Here is for loop, I want to fetch every single status from for loop, which is stored in "readings" variable. I want to that single status (readings ) on front of from within any textbox one by one.
is it possible in `BackgroundWorker`?

Comment: The BackgroundWorker.ProgressChanged event was made for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got answer

```
(sender as BackgroundWorker).ReportProgress((int)(100.0 / totalSteps * i), null);

  void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        progressBar1.Value =(int) e.ProgressPercentage;
    }
```